# Camel: forward message to dynamic destinations (from database)

Tags: spring, validation, apache-camel, message

I am using camel 2.8.4 in my app. my app will receive request from a queue, then the request will be validated by a Validator. Base on the content of the message, the Validator will forward the request to different destinations. Validator will be a POJO bean. Destinations will be get from database (this is a MUST). I prefer to use spring dsl for camelContext.

```
1. I dont know how to write the validator to forward req to destinations.
2. Can we use something similar like this 
    <to uri='method=getURI() bean='Validator''> in camelContext

<camelContext>
       <route id="route-1">
          <from uri="mq:queue:QUEUE"/>
          <bean ref="Validator" method="validate"/>
               <!--i would be great if we can use <to uri="dynamicURI-from-database"> here  -->
       </route> 
</camelContext>

Class Validator{
    public void validate(String req){
     if (...)
         //get uri1 from database 
         String uri1=getURI(..);
         //forward req to uri1
           ...........
     else 
         //get uri2 from database 
          String uri2=getURI(...);
         //forward req to uri2
           ...........

    }

   public String getURI(..){
        ......
      return uri;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [dynamic URI](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html) feature to generate a URI at runtime. You can invoke a processor which sets the URI in exchange and then use that in the to clause.

Something like :

```
process(new Procesor()
   public void process(Exchange exchange){
          exchange.setHeader("myURI",someURI);
});
```

and in the to clause

```
<to uri="${header.myURI}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at the dynamic recipient list pattern: http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use toD provided the destination endpoints are Http APIs. Please refer the link : https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/toD-eip.html